# how to remove dir attribute from tags in xPage build-in CKEditor?

Tags: xpages

in-build CKEditor in xPage (Domino 8.5.3) always add dir attribute to the text container's tags, like P or H2.

For example:

```
<p dir="ltr">test</p>
```

I could change direction "ltr" or "rtl" from the Rich Text Element settings or CKEditor custom config, but I could not remove this attribute at all.

If I use trivial CKEditor, then this attribute absent until I special set up contentsLangDirection property.

So It looks like xPage force this attribute to be set in any case.

Does some one know how to remove it from the in-build CKEditor in xPage ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an XSP.onLoad(...) JS block and remove the attribute.
Curious: what issue is it causing you that you want to remove it?

Comment: I do not need this attribute. Trivially I do my HTML code without this attribute, so I want that code, created in richt text, also was without this attribute. How XSP.onLoad(...) could help me? What I need to write there? change CKEditor config.contentsLangDirection ? I do not like this way - it looks like a hack.

Comment: use a dojo.query to get to the element in html and remove it. But is doesn't seem like a good use of time to investigate that. You don't gain anything by this. I could make a save bet there are other areas that deserve more attention: style management, attachment positioning, a nice img library, support for a thesaurus etc.

Comment: I need to hack this code in to the CKEditor source, coz I need to delete this "dir" even for "source" tab of CKEditor. i.e If I press "source" then HTML must be shown without "dir". I am stop with solution - use open CKEditor. I did custom control that use xp:textarea and open CKEditor

Answer (score 0):

Removing the "dir" attribute is not recommended.

> "The reasoning behind this is to effectively preserve WYSIWYG behaviour."

Not "needing" the attribute seems therefore not a valid argument.

Comment: stackowerflow.com have no dir attribute in the posts, facebook.com  have no dir attribute in the posts. I think, that recomendation is bad and I do not need this atribute, so I am asking how I could force in-build xPage CKEditor to not use it.